# Checking if a user already signed up

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I built a custom authentication system using FirebaseAuthentication tokens.

My signup / login flow should work like this:

1. User presses login button
2. My server generates the authentication token and sends it to the client
3. **Check if the user already exists (in the 'Auth' table or in my database?)**

   - If `true`: sign in using `FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withCustomToken:...`
   - If `false`: Show a form to to enter custom information (name, etc..)

     - sign using `FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withCustomToken:...`
     - save the custom information to my database

My question is: How can I find out if the user has already signed up?
Would a publicly accessible database with only `uid's` be the way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fairly opinion based, but yes, I would use a standalone DB that stores each user's username who has signed up.  Then all that is required is a quick web request through a PHP file querying for any rows returned with that username.

Answer (score 0):

The firebase sign in method will feedback in asynchronous callback.

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithEmail(email, password: password, completion: { (user , error) in
    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }
    self.signedIn(user)
})
```

If you haven't sign up yet. The error will print out

```
There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.
```

Comment: I know, but I'm using `signIn(withCustomToken:`, which creates the user if it doesn't exist and signs the user in if it does exist.